# Comma usage and -ing phrases

Tags: commas

I saw this sentence on a GRE app. The -ing phrase obviously modifies the noun "the highbrows", but is it necessary to have the comma?

> The play dealt with everyday issues and didn't appeal much to the highbrows, looking for intellectual encounters

Comment: No, the comma isn't needed. The sentence is better without it.

Comment: Thanks. Does this extra comma actually make the -ing phrase modify the subject "the play"?

Comment: Well, it doesn't (because that would contradict what we know about the play) but it looks as if it might be about to. If it said, "...and didn't appeal much to the highbrows, talking mostly about rising prices and public transport." it **would** do exactly that, and the comma leads the reader to expect that kind of clause. It tells him/her to pause, which would be wrong. Highbrows looking for things are like men wearing hats: they don't need commas!